# Short table name for SQL Query with Codeigniter database library

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter, I want to using short table name for my SQL Query like that:

```
select pr.name  from product pr where pr.id=12;
```

by using  `db` class, I supposed to do:

```
$this->db->select('pr.name')->from('product pr')->where('pr.id', 12)->get();
```

Comment: What's the question?  Does that not work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Works for me.  CodeIgniter 2.0.2 runs this SQL: ``SELECT `pr`.`name` FROM (`product` pr) WHERE `pr`.`id` = 12``.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?  Are there any errors?  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens when you try that?

Comment: No i want to use database methods  like the second statment : `$this->db->select('pr.name')->from('product pr')->where('pr.id', 12)->get();`

Comment: I know.  I was trying to say, that when I tested it in CodeIgniter 2.0.2, that line worked fine.  It ran the SQL I showed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfect on CI 2.1.3.  Don't forget to use `result()`.

Example works for me:

```
function test(){
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = $this->db->select('pr.order_id')->from('items_table pr')->where('pr.order_id', 2)->get();
    foreach($sql->result() as $item){
        echo $item->order_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this form:

```
$this->db->select('pr.name');
$this->db->from('product as pr');
$this->db->where('pr.id', 4);
return $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

with row_array() you will get one row, with result_array() you will get result of array.

Comment: we can use it for `join` ?

Comment: Yes, you can. For more details, you can read user guide of CI:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

There are so many solutions.. I prefer HMVC, but for demo purpose to explain "how it works", solutions inside controller (terrible,sucks!!!!)

Answer for using shorts table as alias, pls read rtfm or use simple query and generating results

For join methods,you can use too. Happy coding

[image: demo method,]

[image: custom errors]